# How to read wifi signal strength using ROS

Tags: ros, wifi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI all, I am a new user Of ROS I want to read wifi signal strength using ROS .
I  wana ask that
-is there any package to read signal strength?
-is some one one has done this before thaen plaese guide me what steps exactly i should follow?
-any idea to proceed to accomplish this task.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28257/how-to-read-wifi-signal-strength-using-ros/) by [faizi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1741/faizi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-02-22

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-10-18**:
See #q36453

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not aware of any modules that do that already. I guess you would write a new node and parse the output from command line tools like iw.

You might want to follow https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/trac/ticket/123 and http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Planning/IPC/WiFiNeeds as well. ROS fuerte will have a "better" wifi support (Nick Armstrong-Crews: "We wrote a network monitor to keep track of network health (latency, throughput capacity, signal strength").

---

Originally posted by [Cav](https://answers.ros.org/users/1633/cav/) with karma: 345 on 2012-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2